# Using SQLAlchemy and pymysql, how can I set the connection to utilize utf8mb4?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql, utf8mb4

I discovered (the hard way) that [MySQL's UTF8 character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) is only 3 bytes. A bit of research shows I can fix this by changing the tables to utilize the [`utf8mb4`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) collation and get the full 4 bytes UTF should be.

I've done so. My database, tables and columns have all been `ALTER`ed to utilize this charset. However, I still receive this message if I have data that has unicode code points larger than U+FFFF:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='"
```

I discovered I have the following settings:

```
> show variables like '%collation%';

collation_connection  utf8_general_ci
collation_database    utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server      utf8mb4_general_ci
```

The `collation_server` was set by making changes to `my.cnf`. My question, is how do I change the connection one? I currently connect to the database using SQL Alchemy and pymysql like this:

```
connect_string = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?charset=utf8'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DATABASE)
engine = create_engine(connect_string, convert_unicode=True, echo=False)
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
```

What can I do to change from `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8mb4_general_ci` when connecting via SQL Alchemy?

Comment: Interesting.  I was looking for how to define the column in sqlalchemy. How did you do that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Change the `connect_string` to use `charset=utf8mb4`:

```
connect_string = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?charset=utf8mb4'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DATABASE)
```

Comment: is it possible to pass `DATABASE` later to the `engine`?

Comment: The suggestion didn't work in my case, but the other suggestion helped, check the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf