# pd.read_sql from oracle returns decode error

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read data from ORACLE using PANDAS:

```
pd.read_sql(sql, myORACLEinfo)
```

where sql is a select statement

I don't own the ORACLE table, nor I can make change to the table date.

The `pd.read_sql` is returning this error:

```
 refresh 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1101:
 character maps to <undefined>
```

is there a way to escape/ignore this error.
I tried adding:  `encoding='iso-8859-1'` to the alchemy create_engine settings,

assuming ORACLE's default encoding is `iso-8859-1`, but this did not help

Comment: try this pd.read_sql_query(sql,myORACLEinfo)

Comment: you can have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Comment: Which interface are you using to connect? I'd prefer `cx_Oracle.connect` and it works fine for me using the default encoding with Python 3.x.

Comment: what character set is used in your Oracle DB: `select * from nls_database_parameters
 where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'` ?

Comment: Hi MaxU.   Thanks for the QRY.   I ran it and got 'AL32UTF8'.  I am not the DBA and have no control over the setting.

Comment: Hi Kaushik Nayak.  I am using sqlalchemy.create_engine which under the hood id using cx_Oracle.  I am usinf Python 3.7

Comment: After so many failed attempts and so many goole searches, I landed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279863/how-to-use-charset-and-encoding-in-create-engine-of-sqlalchemy-to-create .    using charset=utf8mb4 eliminated the error.  I have no idea why.

Comment: charset=al32utf8 works as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is an encoding issue.
For `python 2.7` and `cx_Oracle 7.3.0`: when you make a connection to `Oracle DB`, you need to specify the encoding type as follows:

```
x_Oracle.connect(username, password, connection_string, encoding="UTF-8")
```

`nencoding parameter = "UTF-8"` can also be specified.

Cheers!